# React Table in Modal with UseState Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having some trouble with the React useState.

I have a modal that I popup based on a form submit.  Prior to the modal being loaded the application calls an api which returns some data that is then displayed within the modal in a table.

I have narrowed down the issue to what looks to be a problem with my code useState of the ingredients array this line:

```
const [editTableData, setEditTableData] = useState(updatedIngredients)
```

My plan is to use this state in my modal to make the ingredient list editable however I removed this from the code that that I could troubleshoot the issues I am facing with just initially setting the state and resetting the state.

My issue is around Resetting State and from what I have read I have tried a couple of approaches.

1. Resetting modal state with a key.  I tried adding this line to the modal setting the key to a unique guid that is generated but this did not work:
   `<Modal key={uuidv4()} show={show} onHide={closeModal} size="xl">`
2. onHide or close or Submit of the modal set the state (setEditTableData) to all null values

   ```
     const initialState = { name: null, quantity: null, unit:null, ingredientId: null }
     const closeModal = () => {
     handleClose(true)      
     setEditTableData({ 
          ...initialState,

         });
     }
   ```

This works to reset the state to all null which fixes an issue I had earlier where the state would display the previous recipes ingredients.  However whenever I reload the modal now after first load the editTableData state is returns as empty and does not get reset with the new updatedIngredients

Full Code:

```
import { Form, Modal, Button, Table } from "react-bootstrap"
import { parseIngredient, parseInstruction } from '@jlucaspains/sharp-recipe-parser';
import axios from "axios";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"
import { useState } from "react"


export default function AddRecipeModal( { show, handleClose, modalTitle, modalImage, modalIngredients, modalSteps }) {


// this parses out the name from the the modalIngredients and returns a new array called updatedIngredients
const updatedIngredients = modalIngredients.map((modalIngredient) => {
    const parsedIngredient = parseIngredient(modalIngredient.raw, 'en')
    return { // <--- return a new object...
      ...modalIngredient, // <--- that has all the properties from modalIngredient...
      // v--- with these properties overwritten
      ingredientId: uuidv4(),
      name: parsedIngredient.ingredient,
      unit: parsedIngredient.unit,
      quantity: parsedIngredient.quantity
    }
  });
  console.log(updatedIngredients)

const [editTableData, setEditTableData] = useState(updatedIngredients)
console.log(editTableData)

// this handle submit is for the add button on the modal to call the backend api to create the recipe
const handleSubmit = async (e : any) => {
    try {
      // this prevents an auto refresh from happening
    //   e.preventDefault() 
      const resp = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/recipe/add", 
      { title: modalTitle, 
        ingredients: updatedIngredients,
        steps: modalSteps,
        image: modalImage
     })
      handleClose(true)
      console.log(resp.data)
    } catch (error : any) {
      console.log(error.response)
    }
  }

  
  //trying to reset the state of EditTableData when the modal is hidden or closed
  const initialState = { name: null, quantity: null, unit:null, ingredientId: null }
  
  const closeModal = () => {
    handleClose(true)      
    setEditTableData({ 
           ...initialState,
           
          });
      }

return (
<Modal key={uuidv4()} show={show} onHide={closeModal} size="xl">
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>
                {modalTitle}
            </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <Form.Group className="container">
                <p><img src={modalImage} height="250px" /></p>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="container">
                <Form.Group className="container">
                <Form.Label><strong>Recipe Ingrededients</strong></Form.Label>
                    <div className="app-container">
                    <Table striped bordered hover>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ingredient</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {updatedIngredients.map(({ ingredientId, name, quantity, unit }) => (
                            <tr key={ingredientId}>
                                <td>{name}</td>
                                <td>{quantity}</td>
                                <td>{unit}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                        )}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                    </div>
            </Form.Group>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="container">
                <Form.Label><strong>Recipe Instructions</strong></Form.Label>
                <div key={uuidv4()}>{modalSteps.map((modalStep) => {
                    // console.log(modalStep)
                    return(
                        <ul>{modalStep.raw}</ul>
                    )
                })}</div>
            </Form.Group>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-end" >
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Add</Button>
            </div>
        </Modal.Body>
    </Form>
</Modal>
)
```

}

Feel like I am just missing something small with this but it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does the `AddRecipeModal` unmount when you close the modal through `handleClose(true)`? If it doesn't then try to have it unmounted and that should fix the issue.
2. If it doesn't unmount and you for some reason don't want to or cannot have it unmount then I suggest using the following:

   useEffect(() => {
   setEditTableData([...updatedIngredients]);
   }, [updatedIngredients]);

This would ensure you have your state updated whenever `updatedIngredients` is updated.

Comment: thank you this worked also realized i needed to set a unique key when initializing the modal.  Your comment helped me find this in another file of the project